# Angular2 Model Driven form format phone number value

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form capturing phone numbers.  I need to update the value entered to match (999) 999-9999 format.  Here's my code:

```
    let formGroup: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group
    ({
        PhoneNumber: ['', CustomValidators.phone('US') ]
    });

    formGroup.valueChanges.debounceTime(1000).subscribe(
        (data) =>
        { 
            let formattedValue = new asYouType('US').input(data);
            formGroup.controls['PhoneNumber'].patchValue(formattedValue);
        }
    );
```

The 'asYouType('US').input(data)' comes from [libphonenumber-js](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/libphonenumber-js).  This is what's used to format the phone number value to 'US' format.

I had to add 'debounceTime(1000)' because a JavaScript error happens when setting the newly formatted value with patchValue causing the valueChanges to fire again.  'debounceTime(1000)' prevents this circular effect.

Is there a better way to format the phone number value?  This seems like a hack approach given I have to use 'debounceTime(1000)'.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `.distinctUntilChanged()` Operator, which prevents from firing as long as the emitted value doesn't change. Put that in front of the `.subscribe()` instead of the `debounceTime()` and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I'm editing the phone number so the value is changing.  My objective is to format the value of the phone number the user is entering.  I want to display phone numbers in (999) 999-999 format as the user is typing the value.